# how to run php artisan migrate from within my virtual machine

Tags: laravel-5, virtual-machine, wampserver, artisan-migrate

I've just started with Laravel, installed on WAMP server, and when trying to migrate the first tables, I get and error saying that homeasted@localhost user has no premission, but I dont know how to change it to work on my virtual machine. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out Laravels [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) – it is easy to setup and provides you with a webserver, ready to use and pre-configured for Laravel.

But if you want to use WAMP, you have to:

1) Create a database for your new Laravel installation. Go to [your local phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin), which comes pre-installed with WAMP Server. Login to your database (default username should be 'root', password is blank). There you can manage your databases. Go ahead and create one for your Laravel installation. (There are many tutorials about [how to create a database with phpmyadmin](http://webvaultwiki.com.au/(S(iungfwenvz2f5c55pioeinil))/Default.aspx?Page=Create-Mysql-Database-User-Phpmyadmin&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1))

2) Go to the root directory of your Laravel installation. Open the file called `.env.example` and fill in your database settings. Then save it to `.env`. This should get your database connection up and running. Read more about `.env` in the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Homestead, you do not need WAMP server. To run `migrate` command, you need to run `vagrant up` to start the VM box and then  run `vagrant ssh` command to run SSH. Only after that you should run `php artisan migrate` command.

Comment: Thank you! that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please check here i think that can help you.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-db-connection-problem

Answer (score 0):

well you can change the table name in `.env` file which is present in the root directory
If it is not present in there (as it is not available in laravel 5.2) please download it.
Enjoy